# Community's test comment can't be removed?

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-flags, community-user

I was viewing a question about anchor tags and clicking them to run some javascript, and below the top answer, I saw that somebody had posted the comment: ["this is a test comment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553135/anchor-tag-with-onclick-and-href-scrolls-to-top/3553142#comment79863619_3553142).

I re-read the post and looked at the dates, and saw that the "test comment" had been posted in 2017, wheras the question and answer were from 2010. And since I couldn't see any reason why it was useful to the question, I opened up the flag dialogue to flag it as "It's not relevant," but got hit with a strange error message.

[image: Unable to flag not relevant comment]

> This comment will be automatically removed by the system when the post is corrected.

I closed the dialogue thinking I must have missed something, like the "this is a test comment" actually had something to do with the post, if it was really indicating something to be corrected or what was going on. Well I had missed something, the author of the comment is Community. So this comment must have been trying to test if the bot can leave a comment or something that required the creation of this comment.

I tried to find more information on this, so I searched for questions regarding community making comments (I didn't find anything but if there are any questions, they're buried under scores of questions and answers about the community needing to be more welcoming with our comments), and having no luck there, I made a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/882807/1094070/list-all-comments-by-community) to list all the comments Community has, and this is the only one. So I don't know what's up with it.

Impressed that the comment was resisting flagging like I had never seen before, I decided to upvote it.

Anyways, the bug is that this comment is not relevant but it can't be flagged as such. Unless of course the comment is somehow needed and I just don't get it, in which case I'd enjoy an explanation as to why this isn't a bug.

Comment: I can't delete it either, with the same error message. I can edit it however.

Comment: Maybe an edit to the post will make it disappear? That might make it think that the "post is corrected"

Comment: It's a magic comment that attract upvotes and we cannot delete it ...

Comment: Given that it's under Nick's post, it's mostly some mischief of his. We need to poke him on Twitter. Also a [SEDE query to get comments by Community is an overkill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=comments)

Comment: @BhargavRao ... Didn't know that you can view a user's comments other than your own lol. Noted for future reference.

Comment: @SamuelLiew "I'm afraid I can't do that, Sam" - Community

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So the reason that error existed was because of the broken links review queue that existed long, long ago. There was an idea that when the system detected a broken link in a post, it would automatically post a comment under the post with a message explaining that the link was broken, and that the comment couldn't be deleted *until the link got fixed*.

That's what the error message is referencing, but that feature was never actually implemented, and the test comment never got deleted. *But the code still exists*, and the code simply looks at "if user == Community" and throws that never-used error message. So now there's no longer a comment anywhere on the site that will trigger that old-as-the-hills error message. Someone will probably remove the code eventually. Maybe. More likely not until someone decides there's another use for comments posted by the Community user.

Comment: *not until someone decides there's another use for comments posted by the Community user.* ... [There already is!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237001/why-does-stackstatus-follow-ryan-seacrest/237002#comment777117_237002)

Comment: The Community user has posted lots of comments like that on Meta Stack Exchange like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/366582). There is a complete list of them [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=comments).

Comment: @DonaldDuck Interesting. We should probably go clean those up too, given that the code that auto-deletes said comments doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @animuson: If found the first paragraph quite confusing. I hope I exchanged the "it"s correctly...