# Community user got suspended in Teams

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, community-user, account-suspension

Earlier today some kind of sock puppetry was spotted in a Teams I'm in.

Shortly afterwards the disruptive behavior stopped, and the involved Teams accounts were gone.

However, this guy got suspended...

[image: community]

Comment: Community's gone rogue, first it comments and removes [delete permissions on the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371989/7795130), and now it's engaging in sock puppetry.  What's next, holding bounties ransom?

Comment: Finally! I'm fed up with that user approving crap edits. "[N]ot really [being] a person" is no excuse. If you can't do the time, don't do the crime.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Community has a badge to prove it's [not a robot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335736).

Comment: sock puppetry in _teams_ ??

Comment: Top 10 Anime Betrayals.

Comment: first step to [skynet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator))?

Comment: For your Team, it's a _miner_ issue.

Comment: 'Keeping a low profile', better luck next time :).

Comment: Really, community? Really?

Comment: Time to snatch away that diamond.

Comment: @user13267 If Community does like the rest of us, and makes a StackOverflow Frankenstein of a program, Skynet won't even boot up.

Comment: Geez, a one year suspension is a bit steep for a first offense! Temporary in the strictest sense, but doesn't really match the expectation of what temporary ought to be.

Comment: Last seen Feb 20th ???

Comment: Possible url used for suspension of the Community user: https://stackoverflow.com/c/charcoal/users/message/create/-1 (team admins only)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It was me all along!

I meant to answer this earlier, but it slipped my mind.

Since the Charcoal Team is kind of a testing ground for whatever comes to mind, I used it as a testing ground for mod tools, doing the kinds of things that would get Nick Craver yelling at me if I did it on SE proper.

- No, you can't delete (or destroy) the Community user. Sad face.
- Yes, you can suspend the Community user. It doesn't... yet... appear to have any adverse effects.

Comment: Sometimes, science can be evil.  This is just *hilarious*.

Comment: The last time it was evil, was when it gave E = mc2.

Comment: More on point, it's been SE policy for a while now that users that have been Suspended in the past year are [ineligible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year) to become moderators *anywhere on the network*. Does that mean that it's time to take that ♦ from Community and keep it away for at least a year?